# Kohana 3 validation for website address

Tags: kohana

I am trying to figure out, how can I validate input field for website address. I have field where users needs to put youtube video address for example http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=biFodVJiqpU . I need to check provided web address against this bit of address http://www.youtube.com/watch?v= , that it is identical. Is it possible to do with Validation rule regex ? If yes, what I need to write in regex array ?

```
 protected $_rules = array(
     'video' => array(
     'not_empty' => NULL,
     'regex' => array(''),
     'exact_length' =>array(42)
     ),
 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex, it should work

```
$pattern = '/^http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch\?v=(.+)$/';
```